# drag & drop function actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, clone

I'm quite new to ActionScript 3 and I'm currently creating a game that there are colour cube that can drag & drop and snap together. Also there are unlimited (clone) drag and drop of the cubes. I managed to snap different colour cubes together but not the cube with same colour. I've tried to set different name for the same colour cube when drop but it does not make a difference. Can anyone help me where is my mistake and how to fix it? Below is my code for the white cube. I'd be grateful for your help:-)

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myWhiteCubes = new MovieClip();
white.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, whitePressed);
function whitePressed (event:MouseEvent):void
{
myWhiteCubes = new White(); 
myWhiteCubes.x = event.stageX;
myWhiteCubes.y = event.stageY;
addChild(myWhiteCubes);
myWhiteCubes.startDrag();
myWhiteCubes.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, cloneWhitePressed);
}

function cloneWhitePressed (event:MouseEvent):void
{
myWhiteCubes = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
addChild(myWhiteCubes);
myWhiteCubes.startDrag();
var topPos:uint = this.numChildren - 1;
this.setChildIndex(myWhiteCubes,topPos);
myWhiteCubes.buttonMode = true;
}

stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, cloneWhiteReleased);
function cloneWhiteReleased (event:MouseEvent) : void
{
myWhiteCubes.stopDrag();

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(myWhiteCubes.x+50,myWhiteCubes.y+10,true))
{   
var whiteCubes : MovieClip = new myWhiteCubes();
    whiteCubes.x = myWhiteCubes.x + 46;
    whiteCubes.y = myWhiteCubes.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestTaro.x+50,latestTaro.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestTaro.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestTaro.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestPurple.x+50,latestPurple.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestPurple.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestPurple.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestBlue.x+50,latestBlue.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestBlue.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestBlue.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestPurple.x+50,latestPurple.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestPurple.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestPurple.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestBlue.x+50,latestBlue.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestBlue.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestBlue.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestTurquois.x+50,latestTurquois.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestTurquois.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestTurquois.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestLime.x+50,latestLime.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestLime.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestLime.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestYellow.x+50,latestYellow.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestYellow.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestYellow.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestOrange.x+50,latestOrange.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestOrange.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestOrange.y;
}

if (myWhiteCubes.hitTestPoint(latestRed.x+50,latestRed.y+10,true))
{   
    myWhiteCubes.x = latestRed.x + 46;
    myWhiteCubes.y = latestRed.y;
}



}

white.buttonMode = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used the

```
var whiteCubes : MovieClip = new myWhiteCubes();
```

inside a if statement , so rather than that , use it below the function declaration

```
function cloneWhitePressed (event:MouseEvent):void
{
var whiteCubes : MovieClip = new myWhiteCubes();
```